# MYSQL: Select entries in relation to multiple rows of multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables that I can't change the structure of:

**facet**

```
id     name
-----------------
1      Series
2      Material
```

**value**

```
id     facet_id     name
----------------------------------
1      2            Glass
2      2            Metal
3      1            Series #1
4      1            Series #2
5      1            Series #3
```

**product_facet_values**

```
product_id     value_id
-----------------------------------
1              1
1              3
2              1
2              4
3              2
3              5
4              1
```

I am trying to write two queries:

/1. One that will return the ids that represent the series facet from the values table where a product record is Glass and has any series. So an output like this:

```
id     facet_id     name
----------------------------------
3      1            Series #1
4      1            Series #2
```

- Record 1 is *not* a series.
- Record 2 is *not* a series.
- Record 3 is returned because product #1 has both a series and material and the material is glass.
- Record 4 is returned because product #2 has both a series and material and the material is glass.
- Record 5 is *not* returned because product #3 has the material of metal even though it has both a series and material.

/2. Same as number one but return a list of product ids.

```
product_id 
---------------
1
2
```

- Product #1 is returned because it has both a series and material and the material is glass.
- Product #2 is returned because it has both a series and material and the material is glass.
- Product #3 is *not* returned because it has the material of metal even though it has both a series and material set.
- Product #4 is *not* returned because it has no series set even though the material is glass.

Comment: sounds great. what have you tried?

Comment: @john-ruddell I haven't cleaned this up but these and variations of these: https://gist.github.com/patrickheeney/f9e47ae81c1e01733111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIRST QUERY:**

try this.. I believe this will do the trick.

```
SELECT 
    v.id
FROM value v
JOIN product_facet_values pfv ON pfv.value_id = v.id
WHERE pfv.product_id IN 
(   SELECT 
        product_id
    FROM product_facet_values
    WHERE
        product_id IN
    (   SELECT 
            product_id
        FROM product_facet_values
        GROUP BY product_id
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
        AND value_id = 1
)
    AND v.facet_id = 1;
```

**SECOND QUERY:**

the inner part of the same query returns the products that have a value of 1 and a value of something other than one so it would be this

```
SELECT 
    product_id
FROM product_facet_values
WHERE
    product_id IN
(   SELECT 
        product_id
    FROM product_facet_values
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
AND value_id = 1
```

## EXPLANATION:

**INNERMOST SUBQUERY:**

```
SELECT 
    product_id
FROM product_facet_values
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

give me products that have more than one record per product (later to be filtered by 'Glass' and 'Series')

**MIDDLE SUBQUERY:**

```
SELECT 
    product_id
FROM product_facet_values
WHERE
    product_id IN
(   
    INNERMOST SUBQUERY
)
AND value_id = 1
```

give me products that have the value_id = 1 (aka 'Glass') that have more than one record.

**OUTERMOST QUERY:**

```
SELECT 
    v.id
FROM value v
JOIN product_facet_values pfv ON pfv.value_id = v.id
WHERE pfv.product_id IN 
(
    MIDDLE SUBQUERY
)
    AND v.facet_id = 1;
```

give me the value id for the products that are related to 'Glass' but whos facet_id = 1 (aka series)

Comment: I think I got the first one. I had to make some minor adjustments because each product can have X number of values and this is just looking for count() > 1. IDs and tables are different: https://gist.github.com/patrickheeney/f48aa2f2e92428d42e1e . Haven't tried the second one yet but should be similar. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I think my revised one is the second query, I was mistaken. Reading your new revision now.

Comment: This one seems to have done it based on your first one: https://gist.github.com/patrickheeney/f48aa2f2e92428d42e1e . Thank you for the explanation, now time to integrate this!

Comment: @Patrick of course! glad I could help :) it took a bit to understand what you were asking though lol